# How to improve factory approach to be able to register dependencies in a right way

Tags: asp.net-core, design-patterns, dependency-injection, refactoring, factory-pattern

I need a code refactoring advice. I have a class which contains several dependencies. I will just provide a constructor, but this should be enough. The class implements this interface:

```
public interface ITopicPublisher<T> {}
```

and the class itself:

```
public class TopicPublisher<T> : ITopicPublisher<T>
{
    public TopicPublisher(IEventGridClient eventGridClient, string topicEndpoint) { ... }
}
```

Now, the instance of this class is injected to the Controllers like this:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
     public SomeController(ITopicPublisher<MyEntity> publisher) { ... }
}
```

in order to create EventGridClient, I need to construct it like this (where key is a simple string):

```
new EventGridClient(new TopicCredentials(key))
```

Now, the topicEndpoint and key are taken from Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(...). It all now is problematic when registering dependencies in ASP.NET (2.2) Startup.cs.

```
builder.Services
    .AddScoped(x => new TopicPublisher<MyEntity>(new EventGridClient(
        new TopicCredentials(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEY"))),
        Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ENDPOINT")))
```

I didn't like it, so I created a factory, like this:

```
public class EnvironmentVariableTopicPublisherFactory
{
    public static ITopicPublisher<T> Create<T>(string topicUrlEnvironmentVariable, string keyEnvironmentVariable) where T : class =>
        new TopicPublisher<T>(new EventGridClient(new TopicCredentials(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(keyEnvironmentVariable))), 
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(topicUrlEnvironmentVariable));
}
```

and now the registration process seem to be a little more simple:

```
builder.Services
    .AddScoped(x => EnvironmentVariableTopicPublisherFactory.Create<MyEntity>("ENDPOINT", "KEY"))
```

I have some concerns however, that I could do it better. Could you give me some hint, how this approach can be made more clean, if this is possible?

Comment: What in specific don't you like in this approach?

Comment: This may be a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @YacoubMassad - hmm... it is not that I don't like it. I'm wondering if it could be done better. For example - with this approach I need to register TopicPublisher whenever there is a new entity. Maybe it could be done in even more generic way - I don't know, just wondering